# Date and Time Difference and Average time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I have two times (basically start time and end time). Also, I have the number of questions played by the user. I wanna know the average time user spent for each question.

```
//startGameTime:    2019-07-27T07:58:42.000Z
//endGameTime:          2019-07-27T07:59:57.000Z
function averageQuestionTime(startGameTime, endGameTime, totalNumberOfQuestions) {

    var d1 = new Date(startGameTime);
    var d2 = new Date(endGameTime);
    var d1msecs = new Date(d1).getTime(); // get milliseconds
    var d2msecs = new Date(d2).getTime(); // get milliseconds
    var avgTime = (d1msecs + d2msecs) / totalNumberOfQuestions;
    var date = new Date(avgTime);
    var hour = date.getUTCHours();
    var min = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var sec = date.getUTCSeconds();
    var day = date.getUTCDate() - 1;
    return (day + ":" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec)
}
```

I understand my logic is completely flawed as the units for date and time and nos of questions are different. What is the best way to achieve the result ?

Comment: *var d1msecs = new Date(d1).getTime();* does not give you what you expect here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). You're looking for *.getUTCMilliseconds();*

Answer (score 2):

There are good libraries which prevent the users from having to reinvent the wheel every time they want to manipulate date/time in Node.

Obtaining time difference is pretty simple (I can see you are doing it correctly to obtain the difference in milliseconds) and libraries make them even simpler.

See how simple it is using momentJS

```
var moment = require('moment');

var startDate = moment('2019-7-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss');
var endDate = moment('2019-7-24 05:27:31', 'YYYY-M-DD HH:mm:ss');

var diffSeconds = endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds');
var diffHours endDate.diff(startDate, 'seconds');

console.log(`Avg in secs: ${diffSeconds / totalNumberOfQuestions}`);
console.log(`Avg in secs: ${diffHours/ totalNumberOfQuestions}`);
```